# Calculation of log for efficiency in math

Tags: algorithm, math, logging

Hello I am weak in maths. but I an trying to solve the problem below. Am I doing it correctly>

Given: that A is big O, omega,or theta of B.

Question is:

> A = n^3 + n   * log(n);
>
> B = n^3 + n^2 * log(n);

As an example, I take n=2.

A=  2^3+2log2 => 8.6

B=  2^3+2^2log2 => 9.2

A is lower bound of B..

I have other questions as well but i need to just confirm the method i am applying is correct or is there any other way to do so.

Am doing this right? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Exactly, so why assume n = 2 ?

Comment: i take it constant for both A and B.

Comment: For A=B n is 2 or i am wrong ?

Comment: The question isn't very clear. Let `^` denote exponentiation. Are you trying to compute O(n^3 + n log n) and O(n^3 + n^2 log n)? If so, remember the *asymptotic* nature of big-O computations, making the result of both these expression O(n^3).

Comment: For each pair of expressions (A,B) below, indicate whether A is O, Ω or Θ of B. Note that zero, one, or more of these relations may hold for a given pair; list all correct ones. Justify your answers.
a) A = n3 + n log n; B = n3 +n2 log n

Comment: this is the question i assume n any value and put in that equation. so if A get smaller than B i write A is lower bound of B

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not about programming per se.

Comment: I know but its related to algorithm that how we find correctness and efficiency of any code or algorithm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 A     n^3 + n  *log(n)     1 + log(n)/n^2
--- = ------------------ = ----------------
 B     n^3 + n^2*log(n)     1 + log(n)/n
```

Since `log(n)/n` and also `log(n)/n^2` have limit zero for `n` trending to infinity, the expressions `1+log(n)/n` and `1+log(n)/n^2` in the canceled quotient `A/B` are bounded to both sides away from zero. For instance, there is a lower bound `N` such that both expressions fall into the interval `[1/2,3/2]` for all `n > N`. This means that all possibilities are true.

Answer (score 1):

The idea behind the big O-notation is to compare the long term behaviour. Your idea (to insert n=2) reveals whether A or B is largest for small values of n. However O is all about large values. Part of the problem is to figure out what a large value is.

One way to get a feel of the problem is to make a table of A and B for larger and larger values of n:

```
           A       B
n=10
n=100
n=1000
n=10000
n=100000
n=1000000
```

The first entry in the table is A for n=10: `A=10^3 + 10*log(10) = 1000+10*1 = 1010`.

The next thing to do, is to draw graphs of A and B in the same coordinate system. Can you spot any long term relation between the two?